# Parallel processing XML nodes with R

Tags: r, xml, parallel-processing

I'm trying to process XML document parallel with R by **xml2** package and **foreach** function. But I'm getting "Error in node_attrs(x$node, nsMap = ns) : external pointer is not valid". Tried to export tree with **clusterExport**.

Example code:

```
library(xml2)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

x <- read_xml("<x> node <yy>1</yy><yy>2</yy></x>")

nCores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(nCores)
clusterExport(cl, varlist = "x")
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(yy = xml_find_all(x, "/x/yy")) %dopar%
  yy

stopCluster(cl)
```

so I don't understand how to avoid this error…

Comment: You example is not very clear.  I am not sure parallel processing will help here, unless you are searching for different tags throughout the document.

Comment: In my example parallel processing is used and not working. Without parallel (%do% instead of %dopar%) example works fine. So the question is why parallel fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xml2 objects (passed via `yy`) can *not* be exported to other R processes because they hold "external pointer" that are unique to the R process (=the main R session) they were created on.  If exported, those external pointers are completely useless on the background R processes (the workers), i.e. they are "not valid".

You can read a bit more about this in Section 'Non-exportable objects' of the ['A Future for R: Common Issues with Solutions'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-issues.html) vignette.

The only parallel solution I am aware of is to keep all xml2 processing unique to each worker, e.g.

```r
res <- foreach(file = files) %dopar% {
   x <- read_xml(file)
   lapply(xml_find_all(x, "/x/yy"), ...)
}
```